# How to replace a string in this case?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm implementing a filter.

I store the filter criteria in a list of string. e.g. 
    List filters

A filter logic as a string e.g.

```
String filterLogic = "(1 AND 2) OR 3";
```

Now I want to replace the numbers with the filter criteria, e.g.

(filters[1] AND filters[2]) OR filters[3])

```
//stores all the filter criterias
        List<String> filters = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= controlGroupId;i++ )
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String fieldsDropdownId="dlFields"+i;
            DropDownList dlFields = (DropDownList)this.FindControl(fieldsDropdownId);
            sb.Append(dlFields.SelectedValue);


            String operatorDropdownId = "dlOperator" + i;
            DropDownList dlOperator = (DropDownList)this.FindControl(operatorDropdownId);
            String operatorValue = dlOperator.SelectedValue;                

            String valuetxbId = "txb" + i;
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.FindControl(valuetxbId);
            String textboxValue = tb.Text;

            switch (operatorValue)
            {
                case "=":
                    sb.Append("=");
                    sb.Append(textboxValue);
                    break;
                case "<>":
                    sb.Append("<>");
                    sb.Append(textboxValue);
                    break;
                case "<":
                    sb.Append("<");
                    sb.Append(textboxValue);
                    break;
                case ">":
                    sb.Append(">");
                    sb.Append(textboxValue);
                    break;
                case ">=":
                    sb.Append(">=");
                    sb.Append(textboxValue);
                    break;
                case "<=":
                    sb.Append("<=");
                    sb.Append(textboxValue);
                    break;
                case "contains":
                    sb.Append(" Like ");
                    sb.Append("'%");
                    sb.Append(textboxValue);
                    sb.Append("%'");
                    break;
                case "does not contain":
                    sb.Append(" Not Like ");
                    sb.Append("'%");
                    sb.Append(textboxValue);
                    sb.Append("%'");
                    break;
                case "starts with":
                    sb.Append(" Like ");
                    sb.Append("'");
                    sb.Append(textboxValue);
                    sb.Append("%'");
                    break;
            }


            filters.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
```

Update:

```
    List<String> l = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
        {
            String s="hello"+i;
            l.Add(s);
        }
        String ss = "(1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 5 AND 6 AND 7 AND 8 AND 9 AND 10 AND 11)";


        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d+");

        ss=rgx.Replace(ss, "l[$0]");
```

This gives me :
"(l[1] AND l[2] AND l[3] AND l[4] AND l[5] AND l[6] AND l[7] AND l[8] AND l[9] AND l[10] AND l[11])"

What I want is:
(hello1 AND hello2 AND hello3 AND hello4 AND hello5 AND hello6 AND hello7 AND hello8 AND hello9 AND hello10 AND hello11)";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given all integers are indices, one can do the following:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex (@"\d+");
rgx.Replace(fitlerLogic, "filters[$0]");
```

Then the result is:

```
"filters[1] AND filters[2]) OR filters[3]"
```

But this **only** works if all integers should be replaced with `filter` indices.

You also made by the way a typo: it's `filterLogic`, not `fitlerLogic`.

**EDIT**: or if you want to substitute it with the real value, you can use a *lambda-expression*:

```
object[] filter = new object[] {false,true,false,true};//not that an array is 0-indexed
Regex rgx = new Regex (@"\d+");
rgx.Replace (fitlerLogic,x => filter[int.Parse(x.Value)].ToString());
```

In that case the result is:

```
"(True AND False) OR True"
```

If you however wish to evaluate the expression, I would take a look to *compiler-compilers* and *context-free grammars*.

Comment: I need to replace with the string stored in list[index]

Comment: @TeemoSinged: do you wish to evaluate the expression: should the result be `true`, or `(true AND false) OR true` for instance?

Comment: Hi CommuSoft, I updated my question, please see the updated part, I am trying to use a Matchevaluator but it allow only one parameter

Comment: @TeemoSinged: well see updated answer, tested this code and it worked... Whether you use an array/list and string/boolean doesn't make much difference.